# ArrayList for a multi-user chat program

Tags: java

Hey there stack overflow.

So I've been working on a chat program to teach myself some Java and I had it operational to the point where any amount of Clients could freely connect to the server, but each client could only communicate to the server.

This is obviously a poor chat program so I implemented an arrayList of Handlers with the goal of sending what one Client writes to all Clients. Problem is I couldn't get it working and now my program crashes after I've typed 3 lines of text between a client and the server.

Please take a look at my code. I will highlight the sections of code I changed when trying to implement the array list. I think I just stuck things into the wrong places.

Server code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;;

    public class Server{
    //----------------------------------------------------
    ArrayList<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();
    //----------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8822);
        while(true){

            Socket s = ss.accept();
            new Handler(s).start();



        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
    }

    class Handler extends Thread{

Socket socket;
boolean notdone;
BufferedReader br;
PrintWriter pw;
String line;


public Handler(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
    notdone = true;
}

public void run(){

    //------------------
    handlers.add(this);
    //------------------

    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()),true);
                    //--------------------------------------------------------
        Iterator<Handler> handlerIterator = handlers.iterator();
                    //--------------------------------------------------------
        while(notdone){

            line = br.readLine();

            if(line.equals("bye")){
                System.out.println("Client said 'bye'");
                notdone = false;
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Echo: " + line);
                            //----------------------------------------------
                while (handlerIterator.hasNext()){
                    Handler current = handlerIterator.next();

                    current.pw.println(line);

                }
                            //----------------------------------------------
            }

        }
        br.close();
        pw.close();
        socket.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Client severed connection.");
    }
}
    }
```

As for the client, I think I should change something in the highlighted section,
but I'm not sure what.

Client Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client{

public static void main(String[] args){


    try{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8822);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()),true);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean notdone = true;

        while(notdone){
            String outString = scan.nextLine();
            if(outString.equals("bye")){
                pw.println(outString);
                notdone = false;
            }else{
                            //------------------
                pw.println(outString);
                String inString = br.readLine();
                            //------------------

                System.out.println("Received: " + inString);
            }
        }
        br.close();
        pw.close();
        s.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Server severed connection.");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: If you post some log, showing the error, it would be easier to debug.

Comment: There are no errors. It compiles just fine. When i run Server and Client in command prompt it runs, but after I say send the server say .. hello twice. It just hangs. If I close it it just gives me my severed connection try catch. There is a logic error somewhere with my iterator or perhaps "handlers.add(this);" is in the wrong location.

Comment: how about you print the exception in the catch block?

Comment: "Server severed connection."
That's not the problem. It just iterates twice as opposed to continuing to iterate.

The error is here

while (handlerIterator.hasNext()){
                    Handler current = handlerIterator.next();

                    current.pw.println(line);

or there is an issue where i am adding handlers.add(this) as this should be the client.

Like i said, it's a logic error so error messages won't help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one bug for you:

```
    Iterator<Handler> handlerIterator = handlers.iterator();
    while(notdone){
        // ...
        while (handlerIterator.hasNext()){
            Handler current = handlerIterator.next();
            // ....
        }
    }
```

The first time you go through the outer loop, you'll run through the inner loop.  The *second* time through the outer loop, `handlerIterator` is already exhausted, so it will return `false` for `hasNext()` and you'll never get into the inner loop again.

Instead, use a for-each loop:

```
    while(notdone){
        // ...
        for (Handler current : handlers){
            // ....
        }
    }
```

This is equivalent to (but more succinct than)

```
    while(notdone){
        // ...
        Iterator<Handler> handlerIterator = handlers.iterator()
        while (handlerIterator.hasNext()){
            Handler current = handlerIterator.next();
            // ....
        }
    }
```

Meanwhile, on the client side,

```
            pw.println(outString);
            String inString = br.readLine();
```

says that you read from the server only and always after writing to the server.  So a client can't just listen.  This should be OK with a single client, but if you have two clients, then you'll get this:

1. ClientA sends "hello" to Server
2. Server prints "hello" to both client streams
3. ClientA reads "hello" from its buffer (ClientB has not read anything)
4. ClientB sends "world" to Server
5. ClientB reads "hello" from its buffer
6. Server prints "world" to both client streams

So now both clients have seen ClientA's message but not ClientB's.  You'll keep getting this weird delay effect and eventually the buffers will fill up and block.

The real solution to this is that each client needs to have a separate thread for reading and writing.  But that's a pretty big jump in the code difficulty.  I think you should look at [BufferedReader#ready()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29), which tells you if there's data waiting to be read.  On the client side, you can use this at the beginning of your while-not-done loop:

```
while(br.ready()) {
    String inString = br.readLine();
    // ...
}
// Now all the messages from the server have been printed
```

You'll still have the problem of clients needing to talk continually, but as long as they do that, things should work.